# Make Firefox connect to local domain without internet connection

Tags: networking, firefox, local

Why does Firefox require a network connection to load pages on locally hosted domains?  I know an internet connection is not required, just network.

I'm using Linux Mint 17.

Comment: This question could benefit by including your operating system version

Comment: Have you activated DHCP? Maybe a static IP address works?

Comment: @Chris DHCP on the router? I'm trying to load the site without going through the router.

Comment: No, I meant the IP settings on your local machine. Under the IPv4 settings of your Local Network Adapter your can set "Obtain IP address automaticvally" (=DHCP) or set a fix IP address.

How do you connect your machine to the network? Do you use also a router?

Comment: I normally connect wirelessly and set the IP address myself.